# Pause UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am making a timer app. The user sets the time and the app counts down from there. I have added a UILocalNotification, so that it pops up even when you aren't in the app to tell you the timer has finished:

IN MY VIEW CONTROLLER:

```
- (void)setupLocalNotifications {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

totalSeconds = (setHour * 60 * 60) + (setMinute * 60) + (setSecond);

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *dateToFire = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:totalSeconds];

localNotification.fireDate = dateToFire;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Timer Done";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1; // increment

NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Object 1", @"Key 1", @"Object 2", @"Key 2", nil];
localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

IN MY APPDELEGATE:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.;

ScrollViewController *sv = [[ScrollViewController alloc] init];

UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

if (notification) {
    [self showAlarm:notification.alertBody];
    NSLog(@"AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

self.window.rootViewController = sv; // Make tab bar controller the root view controller
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
[self showAlarm:notification.alertBody];
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
NSLog(@"AppDelegate didReceiveLocalNotification %@", notification.userInfo);
}

- (void)showAlarm:(NSString *)text {
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Timer"
                                                    message:text
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Stop Timer"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
}
```

What happens is, I set a UILocalNotification to go off after the user-defined number of seconds has passed. However, my app allows you to pause the timer. When paused, the UILocalNotification will carry on, and go off after the seconds have passed. Is there any way to pause the local notification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A local notification cannot be paused. If the timer is paused in your application,
you should *cancel* the notification, and create/schedule a new one if the timer
is resumed.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Is that done by setting localNotification to nil?

Comment: @user2397282: No. If you have only one notification then the easiest method is to call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]`.

Comment: Or keep a pointer to the notification object and use cancelLocalNotification, if there are multiple and you only want to cancel the one.

Comment: (Though when I look at UILocalNotification I see that fireDate is a property, and nothing is said about it being read-only.)

Comment: @HotLicks: That is of course correct. I just wanted to keep it simple as OP's existing code already cancels *all* notifications before creating a new one. - And yes, setting the fire date to `[NSDate distantFuture]` would be an alternative, I did not think of that. Good idea!

Comment: Yeah, the only time I've used (long time in the future) time-based notifications I cancelled all of them and rescheduled vs doing it one at a time.  Was far simpler to just keep a table of scheduled times & rep rates (daily/weekly/monthly) and reschedule everything.